pdflatex can't parse webman.tex
I installed mactex via brew on a recent M2 Mac laptop. Then I ran pdflatex sample2e.tex, and it produced a nice PDF.
Then I downloaded webman.tex from the zip link at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/web
Then I tried to run pdflatex webman.tex. It stops in the console complaining about a legit-looking \\def (I found it on line 1220):
\def\\#1{\hbox{\it#1\/\kern.05em}} % italic type for identifiers
When I type R in the console to continue running, it produces over 100 errors and then quits.
Anyone understand why this fails?

webman is not latex, use pdftex not pdflatex

Welcome to TeX.SE!

You did not show the error message. The console would have shown
$ pdflatex webman
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./webman.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/plain/knuth-lib/webmac.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
\\#1->\hbox {\it 
                 #1\/\kern .05em}
l.138 \mark{\noexpand\nullsec{\rhead
                                    }}
? 

So the error is that \it is not defined.
The real problem though is that the file is plain TeX not LaTeX, so use pdftex not pdflatex then the console will show
$ pdftex webman
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./webman.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/plain/knuth-lib/webmac.tex) [1{/usr/loc
al/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] [3] [4]
[5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [200] [201] [202] [203] [204]
[205] [206] [207] )</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfo
nts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
ts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfont
s/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/
cm/cmr7.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmr8.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr
9.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsl10
.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmssq8.
pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmssqi8.
pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.p
fb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb
></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtex10.pfb
></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb><
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt8.pfb>
Output written on webman.pdf (22 pages, 292252 bytes).
Transcript written on webman.log.



Wow, thank you David, for that quick response. Did not know the distinction between the two commands, but now I do. Makes perfect sense.
